# Convert multiple rows to columns - Not using PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I know there are many posts about this, but I can't seem to find one that applies. I want to put values that are causing multiple rows into separate columns so that I only have one row of data. Here's a specific example:

```
SELECT ID, FavoriteColor
FROM MyColorTable
```

Since users can enter multiple favorite colors - Results:

```
ID      FavoriteColor
856     Blue
856     Red
122     Purple
909     Blueish-Pink
```

I need it to format as (Note - I cannot use PIVOT):

```
ID      FavoriteColor1      FavoriteColor2
856     Blue                Red
122     Purple
909     Blueish-Pink
```

Can someone help me figure this out? Maybe with CASE statements? I've spent too many hours fiddling with my SQL.

Comment: what is the RDBMS (what type of SQL is this?); do you have a maximum number of color entries?  Does this need to be dynamic or are you ok hard coding/creating lots of columns if necessary?

Comment: You need a row number and conditional aggregation.  The row number is easy unless you are on MySQL then it is a little more complicated but still easy enough.  So please tag your RDBMS sql-server, Oracle, mysql...etc!

Comment: SQL Server. Ideally it would be dynamic. There is no max color entry, but if I needed to, I could code FavoriteColor1 - FavoriteColor5 and hope no one has more than 5.

Comment: You'll probably want to specify which version of SQL Server also.

Comment: It's not actually SQL Server, it just uses the same structure. The software I'm writing my SQL in stands independently and is just a free form box. There are others using this program who have had SQL Server access the database and used that tool to write their SQL and then just moved that SQL into the program's text box. So SQL Server is the closest comparison, as far as structure, that I can provide. As far as I know, they are accessing version 8 or 12. Some may be using 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't go dynamic, a conditional aggregation may help

```
Select ID
      ,FavoriteColor1 = max(case when RN=1 then FavoriteColor else '' end)
      ,FavoriteColor2 = max(case when RN=2 then FavoriteColor else '' end)
From  (
        Select *
              ,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by FavoriteColor)
         from YourTable
      ) A
Group By ID
```

Returns

```
ID  FavoriteColor1  FavoriteColor2
122 Purple  
856 Blue            Red
909 Blueish-Pink
```

Comment: Thanks John! That did it. I was mixing up the fields I was inserting into Partition By and Order By. It's even more frustrating to know that I was that close all day. It would still be ideal to have it dynamic, but as long as I can make it work right now, I can continue to work on that part.